# Calculating variance

Tags: self-study, variance

[image]

I am provided the following details (see picture) about a sample whereby $x$ is logarithm of income. How do I calculate the sample variance from this information?

Comment: Try using var$(X) = E[X^2] - \left(E[X]\right)^2$.

Comment: Please look at the wikipedia for explaination if you're stuck.

Comment: I am still confused.. I know this formula but how do I apply it in this situation?

Comment: Are you computing the variance of $x$ or the variance of income?

Comment: the variance of x which will be the variance of income

Comment: @Alex Your last comment is contradictory to your question. In your question, you say $x$ is logarithm of income and in your comment you say $x$ is income.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might do you some good to review the general formula for the sample variance, $\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2\over{n-1}.$  Then explore how you might be able to algebraically manipulate this formula so that you can use the statistics or pieces of information that you have about the sample to solve the problem.